# Python - How to properly read virtual file systems

Tags: python, ftp, filesystems, webdav, virtualfilesystem

I've recently looked in to the Virtual File Systems module for Python (http://packages.python.org/fs/), and have run in to a quick question on how to properly use it.

I've created myself an FTP virtual file system using the following lines:

```
from fs.ftpfs import FTPFS

FTP = FTPFS(host='127.0.0.1', user='test1', passwd='test1', acct='', timeout=60, port=21, dircache=True)
```

Simple right?

Now my question is how would I have another python script read inside this file system? For example, I'm using a PyWebDav, and the default directory is set to "C:\WebDir". How can I set it to look inside my virtual file system I've just created instead?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**

I'm attempting to put this as the 'Directory" for pyWebDav:

```
from fs.ftpfs import FTPFS
ftpServer = FTPFS(host='127.0.0.1', user='test1', passwd='test1', acct='', timeout=60, port=21, dircache=True)
ftpServer = ftpServer.listdir(path='./', wildcard=None, full=True, absolute=True, dirs_only=False, files_only=False)
directory = ftpServer
```

Just after running, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dustin\Documents\ftpmirror\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    server.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywebdav-0.9.4.1-py2.7.egg\DAVServer\server.py", line 369, in run
    handler=handler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywebdav-0.9.4.1-py2.7.egg\DAVServer\server.py", line 75, in runserver
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Just thought I'd show examples on how I want to use Virtual File Systems in hope to make thing easier. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`fs` provides a common interface to diffferent filesystems. To take advantage of it your program need to use the interface. `pyWebDav` doesn't use the interface. It uses `os.path` functions.

[`listdir()`](http://packages.python.org/fs/base.html#fs.base.FS.listdir) returns a *list* of files, directories, but `os.path.isdir()` expects a single string. It leads to the error that you see.

Comment: There's no methods to make os seem like it's reading through the filesystem? Or even a library for converting OS functions to FS? (Going to be doing some Goolging as well.)

Comment: @Dustin have you found the answer? I'm having the same problem. I thought that maybe those FS URL's could be the answer, but I couldn't find a proper way to reference them.